Why does "," this query cause error even it is right?
CREATE DATABASE Customers;

USE Customers;

CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    customer_Id int, 
    First_Name Varchar(15)
);

INSERT INTO customer (customer_Id, First_Name)
VALUES ( (1, 'John') );

Error :

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Here's a screenshot for reference - can somebody help with this?
SQL

You don't need the extra set of inner parentheses around (1,'John').  You already have an opening parenthesis here Values( and a closing one here );.

Your insert syntax is off, and the VALUES clause should just be a single level list of CSV tuples:
INSERT INTO customer(customer_Id, First_Name)
VALUES
    (1, 'John'),
    (2, 'Jon'),
    ...;


I assume you are using TSQL (Microsft SQL Server) since the error report looks similar to it, if that's the case, you should remove the outer parenthesis () after keyword Values.
For example:
INSERT INTO Table1(columns...)
VALUES
(vals1)

INSERT INTO Table1(columns...)
VALUES
(vals1),
(vals2),
...

Where each vals is the combination of one row values.
To solve your problem:
INSERT INTO Customer(customer_Id, First_Name)
VALUES
(1, 'John')


Try removing the closing parenthesis [“);”] after the (1,”John”)
